# variance and generating function - probability hat problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Posted this previously but couldn't comment on it with the temp account i created so:

We have a $3$ hat experiment where $(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (3,2,1)$ have a $\frac{1}{5}$ probability and $(2,3,1), (3,1,2)$ have a $\frac{1}{10}$ probability. Find the variance of N where N is the # of people who get their own hat.

I obtained the expected value which is $1.2$ or $\frac{6}{5}$. I tried to obtain the variance two different ways but both are wrong as the answer is $\frac{24}
{25}$.

I found the frequency function of $f(0)=\frac{2}{10}$, $f(1)=\frac{6}{10}$ or $\frac{3}{5}$, and $f(3)=\frac{2}{10}$ or $\frac{1}{5}$
$1.2(\frac{4}{10})(1-\frac{4}{10}) + 1.2(\frac{6}{10})(1-\frac{6}{10}) + 1.2(\frac{2}{10})(1-\frac{2}{10})$.

The other way i did it was: $1.2(\frac{1}{10})(1-\frac{1}{10}) + 1.2(\frac{1}{10})(1-\frac{1}{10}) + 1.2(\frac{1}{5})(1-\frac{1}{5}) + 1.2(\frac{1}{5})(1-\frac{1}{5}) + 1.2(\frac{1}{5})(1-\frac{1}{5}) + 1.2(\frac{1}{5})(1-\frac{1}{5}) = .984$

which does not equal $\frac{24}{25}$ either.

Also how would i calculate E(N) by using generating a function? I'm not sure how to create a function to reflect the problem. I tried (1+x)^3 but i wouldn't know what to get the derivative of.

Answer (score 1):

Variance is $E[(X-\bar{X})^2]$. Here $\bar{X}=1.2$, so we have
$$Var = 0.2*(0-1.2)^2 + 0.6*(1-1.2)^2 + 0.2*(3-1.2)^2$$
So $$Var = 0.96 = 24/25$$

Comment: How would i make a generated function to get the same expected result as above?

Answer (score 0):

Use $\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$. $$E[X^2] = \frac{1}{5}(3^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2) + \frac{1}{10}(0^2 + 0^2)=\frac{12}{5}$$

Then $E[X^2]-E[X]^2=\frac{12}{5}-\frac{36}{25}=\frac{24}{25}$

---

Using generating functions, as requested. Given a random variable $X$, the moment generating function is the function $M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$. $X$ is given by

$$P(X=0)=P(X=3)=\frac{1}{5},P(X=1)=\frac{3}{5}$$
so
$$\begin{align}
E[e^{tX}] &= \frac{1}{5}\left( e^{0t}+e^{3t} \right)+\frac{3}{5}e^{t} \\ &=\frac{1}{5}\left( 1+e^{3t}+3e^{t} \right)
\end{align}$$

Using this, the *first moment* or *expected value* is given by $M_X'(0)$. $$M_X'(t)=\frac{1}{5}\left(3e^{3t}+3e^{t} \right) \implies M'_X(0)=\frac{6}{5}$$

The second moment, or $E[X^2]$ is given by $M_X''(0).$
$$M_X''(t)=\frac{1}{5}\left( 9e^{3t}+3e^{t}\right) \implies M_X''(0)=\frac{12}{5}$$

Once again, using the same identity $\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ we get $\text{Var}(X)=\frac{12}{5}-\frac{36}{25}=\frac{24}{25}$

Comment: How would i make a generated function to get the same expected result as above?

Comment: What do you mean a "generated function"?

Comment: like this:
http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/fall05/ln11.pdf

Comment: @user2369869 see edit

Comment: Thank you! But i'm a little confused now, this seems really different than the examples used in that pdf. In the pdf it uses generated functions to count the number of ways to do something by taking the derivative. But this is not the same usage as creating a generated function and finding its derivative to find the expected value(what you did above) correct? Also in the pdf there is example of creating a generated function to reflect a sequence of values. But what is the purpose of that? It seems like the use of generated functions varies which is confusing.

Comment: @user2369869 ahhh I see your confusion here. I'll be honest, I hadn't actually looked at the PDF until right now—I had assumed that you were referring to the [moment generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), which is a common tool in probability, and not just general [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). The moment generating function *does* encode information about a sequence of values: $M_X(t)=E[e^tX]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty E[X^n]\frac{t^n}{n!}$, so it is the [exponential generating function] of the sequence of moments.